# Calling a web service from php?

Tags: php, web-services

All,

Atlast had our admin install the PEAR SOAP module on our apache server. Now when i try the following code - it is giving me an error "HTTP Bad Request". Can anyone help?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
/* Include PEAR::SOAP's SOAP_Client class: */
require_once('SOAP/Client.php');
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
?>

<form action="wszip.php" method="post">
<table cellspacing="10" bgcolor="CadetBlue">
<tr>
<td><B>Enter Zip Code : </B><input type="text" name="zip" /></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="Submit" value="Find It!"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<BR><BR><BR><BR>
</form>

<?php
if($zip != "")
{
    $wsdl_url = "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL";
    $wsdl     = new SOAP_WSDL($wsdl_url);
    $client   = $wsdl->getProxy();
    $params = array('USZip' => $zip);
    $response = $client->GetInfoByZIP($params);
    echo $response;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<?php
require_once('SOAP/Client.php');
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
?>

<form action="wszip.php" method="post">
<table cellspacing="10" bgcolor="CadetBlue">
<tr>
<td><B>Enter Zip: </B><input type="text" name="zip" /></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="Submit" value="Find It!"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
if($zip != "")
{
 $wsdl_url = "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL";
 $wsdl     = new SOAP_WSDL($wsdl_url);
 $client   = $wsdl->getProxy();
 $params = array('USZip' => $zip);
 $response = $client->GetInfoByZIP($params);
 echo $response;
}
?>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be

```
$client   = $wsdl->getProxy();
// don't wrap it into another array.
// $params = array('USZip' => $zip);
$response = $client->GetInfoByZIP($zip);
var_dump( $response );
```

but before seeing any results my screen is flooded with "PHP Deprecated:" and "PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method ..." messages. I'd rather use the [soap extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)

```
<?php
echo PHP_VERSION, ' ', PHP_OS, "\n";
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL');
$response = $client->GetInfoByZIP(array('USZip'=>'10006'));
var_dump($response);
```

unfortunately the response is defined as

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetInfoByZIPResult">
    <s:complexType mixed="true">
        <s:sequence>
            <s:any/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

which roughly translated means "the response will be ...something", i.e. you have to parse the xml "manually".

```
<?php
echo PHP_VERSION, ' ', PHP_OS, "\n";
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL');
$response = $client->GetInfoByZIP(array('USZip'=>'10006'));
```

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($response->GetInfoByZIPResult->any);
echo 'City: ', $doc->Table->CITY[0];prints

```
5.3.0RC4 WINNT
City: New York
```

Comment: Yeah .. the <any/> element has got to be the most ridiculous part of the whole SOAP spec.